# Facebook Java SDK | Marketing API Error #803

Tags: java, facebook, https

I am currently trying to use the Facebook Java SDK to publish ads automatically.

I am just attempting to test my API Authentication using the basic facebook demo code they have provided: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/business-sdk/getting-started/

Here is where I define my APIContext so that I can instantiate my AdAccount:

```
public static final APIContext context = new APIContext(
        "{App Auth Token}",
        "{App Secret}"
);
```

When I execute `System.out.println(context.getAppID());` I am returned the ID of the App I have set up within developers.facebook. At this point I think everything is working as intended...?

I then attempt to execute the following code:

```
AdAccount account = new AdAccount("act_{10405322}", context);
    try {
        APINodeList<Campaign> campaigns = account.getCampaigns().requestAllFields().execute();
        for(Campaign campaign : campaigns) {
            System.out.println(campaign.getFieldName());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My application keeps failing with this response:

```
com.facebook.ads.sdk.APIException$FailedRequestException: {"error":{"message":"(#803) Some of the 
aliases you requested do not exist: 
act_{10405322}","type":"OAuthException","code":803,"fbtrace_id":"A3uiRKVWUVQyMqZO9GIfWAY"}}
```

Could someone explain to me why this is the case? `act_{10405322}` is the ad account I am attempting to reach, so I am not sure why the "alias does not exist"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After rigorous testing, I found two issues that solved my error.

1. I was using a App Token rather than a Page Access Token
2. I changed act_{10405322} to act_10405322 and I finally got a successful response.